# Setting up Embedded LaTeX in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

According to the [org mode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Embedded-LaTeX.html) for emacs, one can view pieces of LaTeX code embedded in an org-file. This is supposed to be default behavior bound to the keys `C-c C-x C-l` which invokes the `org-preview-latex-fragment` command. Unfortunately, this does not work for me and I cannot figure out why. I do not get an error, it is just that nothing happens...

I use emacs 24.3. Checking all the settings, I did `M-x customize-group` then typed `org-latex`. This opens up a window in which I can specify the values of certain variables/functions pertaining to `org-latex`. The `org-latex-create-image-formula-program` variable is set to `dvipng`. I checked that I do indeed have dvipng installed via `apt-get` on Ubuntu 12.04. The other variables in this window seemed find or not relevant to making this functionality work

1. How can I get embedded LaTeX to work inside emacs?

Please help me!

Comment: It works for me, Emacs 24.3 with Org 20140106 installed via ELPA.  Do you get any error?

Comment: I would imagine that `org-mode` uses the same codebehind as `preview-latex`, now embedded in AUCTeX.  If you use AUCTeX and try to preview the document, do you get a similar result?

Comment: Are you on windows or on e.g. Linux? Because any preview under windows IMO requires installation of quite a lot of dlls and whatever software. Besides that, I found the workflow of writing in orgmode and printing in LaTeX quite a nuisance. The export is fragile and you cannot really concentrate on you work.

Comment: As my description says, I use emacs 24.3 and Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus you didn't answer to the first two questions.

Comment: I downloaded the latest org source from github a few days ago, and I am not getting an error. Nothing happens. I do not use AucTex

Comment: @giordano, please post an answer, so I can delete mine.

Comment: @doed what should be the content of the answer?  Updating Org doesn't fix the bug.  For the time being, I don't have a clue what could be the problem.

Comment: @giordano, I understand. CodeKingplusplus why did you install org from github?